# Laravel - Image does not appear in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel, and I want to display an image. I have the public/img folder, and this is the code

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset("img/background1.jpg") }}" alt="Unsplashed background img 1">
```

The image does not appear. When I inspect the page however, it returns the correct link, http://localhost:8000/img/background1.jpg but it says 0x0 px.

Comment: Could you post the html that's returned?

Comment: '<img src="http://localhost:8000/img/background1.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 1">'

Comment: What happens when you open `http://localhost:8000/img/background1.jpg` directly in your browser?

Comment: It opens the image.

Comment: Looks like the semi colon in the img element might be breaking things.

Answer (score 1):

Add a / in front as the public folder is the root...

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset("/img/background1.jpg") }}" alt="Unsplashed background img 1">
```

Comment: Tried, nothing.

Comment: Try just ```src="{{ asset('img/background1.jpg') }}"```.  Also, make sure the file is in your `public/img` directory.

Comment: Tried that too, and yes,the image is there, when I hover over the link in html it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting correct image when you open this link in browser? If so, then it would be issue with img height-width. Try setting static height-width for img and check.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Yes I get the correct image, but when I hover over it, it says 0x0 px.

Comment: try `<img src="{{ URL::asset("img/background1.jpg") }}" alt="Unsplashed background img 1" style="height: 100px; width: 100px">`, if this works then the problem would be with container size.

Comment: Also doesen't work. The thing is, I copied the code from a template, which works, and just changed the image.